# How to delete/edit row and column dynamically from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a table where I am adding row and column dynamically. I want to delete/edit row and column which I am adding. I have included my code

```js
$('#irow').click(function(){
    if($('#row').val()){
        $('#mtable tbody').append('<tr><td>Some Item</td></tr>');
        $('#mtable tbody tr:last td:first').html($('#row').val());
    }else{alert('Enter Text');}
});
$('#icol').click(function(){
    if($('#col').val()){
        $('#mtable tr').append($("<td>"));
        $('#mtable thead tr>td:last').html($('#col').val());
        $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function(){$(this).children('td:last').append($('<input type="text">'))});
    }else{alert('Enter Text');}
});
```

```css
td{padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" id="mtable">
    <thead><tr><td>Employee \department</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table><br/><br/>
<input id="row" placeholder="Enter Employee Name"/><button id="irow">Add Employee</button><br/><br/>
<input id="col" placeholder="Enter department Name"/><button id="icol">Add department</button>
```

Please help me to delete/edit row and column in table

Comment: How do you know which row or column to remove? Would you have a row index, or...? In any case, can't you just select the tr or tds in question and call `.remove()`?

Comment: is it possible to delete rows and edit for columns ?

Comment: Again, you need to identify which row or column you want to delete or edit. To change the content of an existing cell, use `.html()` or `.text()`.

Comment: could you please help me with a fiddle? it will be great favour

Answer (score 0):

create another input and button as illustrated in the fiddle
then enter the index of the row to delete. you can decide to subtract but entering 0 will delete the first row.

```
<code>
    $('#dcol').click(function(){
       var index = $('#col').val();
        $('#mtable tbody').find('tr').eq(index).remove()
    })
```

I prepared a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vdab98xk/

To delete columnns

```
$('#mtable tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td').eq(index).remove(); 
})
```

To edit Column

```
$('#mtable tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(index).text('New Value');
```

Comment: it is deleting top row only not the value i am entring to delete.

Comment: You want to delete the column? or add a new column?

Comment: i want to delete column

Comment: 0 will delete first row, 1 will delete second row etc.

Comment: in that case I will give another solution, but you will take the index of the entire column you want to delete.

Comment: No. only selected row or column has to be deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137127/discussion-between-arpit-gupta-and-jidexl21).